# Eclipse RCP: check if a job has finished

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, user-interface, eclipse-rcp

I want to check if a [Job](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2Fjobs%2FJob.html) has finished. Currently I do this:

```
 if ( traceJob.getState() != Job.WAITING && traceJob.getState() != Job.RUNNING){
```

But I think there should be a better way to check. Anyone has any good idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Job.addJobChangeListener` to add a listener to a Job. The `done` method of the listener is called when the job finishes. There is a `JobChangeAdapter` class with default implementations of all the `IJobChangeListener` methods so that you don't need to implement all of them.

You can use `Job.getJobManager().join(family, progress monitor)` to wait for a Job to finish. This requires your Job to override the `belongsTo` method to test which family the Job belongs to. There is also `Job.join()` to wait for a specific job to finish.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to directly check it (because NONE is also returned, before a job is scheduled to run).

You might want to use add a

boolean 
    finished=false
to the Job.

it should be false on initialization, set to true as soon as the job finished (somewhere in method done() maybe?)